# how to call the external controller using resolve in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, resolve

how to call the external controller using resolve in angularjs

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute']);

mainApp .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {


    $routeProvider

        // home page

          .when('/', {
              templateUrl: 'Samples/accordion.html',
              controller: "AddStudentController",
          })
});

accordion.html

<h1>AddStudent</h1>

mainApp.controller('AddStudentController', function($scope) {

     $scope.message = "This page will be used to display add student form";

         });
```

how to call the controller using resolve.

Please share your suggestions,

Comment: Why u are trying to call the controller using resolve.?

Comment: Can you elaborate why do you want to call controller using Resolve, The use of resolve is that if you want to perform any actions before some controllers gets executed you use resolve to achieve it, You can move the logic that you want to execute to a service and use that service in a  resolve block,  hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I want to call the externall controller., I have to call these controllers and scope values without referring thescripts in the head section of the HTML page. Is there any possible way to call the external controller from script section without using any third party plugin.
is this achieved by any other option.?